# be $A,B$sets, show that $(A\setminus B) \sim (B\setminus A)$ then $A \sim B $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Be $\sim $ an equivalence relation.

Suppose that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $A \setminus B = A$,  same to $B \setminus A$

Then, $A \setminus B \sim B \setminus A = A \sim B$

How can i show it when $A \cap B \neq \emptyset $, also the reciprocal is correct, i think is not but i can´t think in a good counterexample.

Comment: What is "~"?---

Comment: Are you assuming $\sim$ an equivalence relation?

Comment: yes, is an equivalence relation

Comment: I doubt *every* equivalence relation satisfies $((A\setminus B)\sim(B\setminus A))\implies A\sim B$.

Comment: @J.G. can u show me a counterexample? I just assumed that the statement was correct.

Comment: @KentaS beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\sim B$ when either $|A|=|B|=1$ or $A=B$. This is an equivalence relation.

Now, letting $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$, we see that $A\setminus B\sim B\setminus A$ but $A\not\sim B$.

Comment: But here, $|A|=|B|$

Comment: $|A|=|B|=2$, not $1$, so by definition they are not equivalent

Comment: oh, but u tell me that just when$ |A|=|B| = 1$ so when $A \cap B $ different of empty the statement is not correct right?.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer.